# Microsoft Teams conversational bot crashes during SSO

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

During the process of SSO inside of a conversational bot in Microsoft Teams, my waterfall crashes inside of the `OAUTH_PROMPT` dialog invoked from the botbuilder-dialogs node JS module.

When the user sends the "sign-in" command, the bot crashes and gets the error:

```
DialogContextError: OAuthPrompt.recognizeToken(): not supported by the current adapter
    at /Users/celine/dev/monia/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:39:19
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/Users/celine/dev/monia/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/dialogContext.js:6:65)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  error: Error: OAuthPrompt.recognizeToken(): not supported by the current adapter
      at OAuthPrompt.<anonymous> (/Users/celine/dev/monia/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/prompts/oauthPrompt.js:355:27)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (/Users/celine/dev/monia/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/lib/prompts/oauthPrompt.js:5:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5),
  dialogContext: {
    activeDialog: 'OAuthPrompt',
    parent: 'SsoDialog',
    stack: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}

 [onTurnError] unhandled error: DialogContextError: OAuthPrompt.recognizeToken(): not supported by the current adapter
```

My code is gotten from this Microsoft sample :
[bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/js)

**This is a code that has been tested and works fine with a local side-loaded app.**

The Oauth Connection works fine when tested through the Azure Portal (Azure-bot/Configuration).
We have checked with the validation team [the configuration of the App Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-register-aad?tabs=windows#to-configure-an-authorized-client-application) and of the [Azure-bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-teams-conversation-bot?tutorial-step=2) and everything seems fine and done accordingly.

This is the code that I'm using (note that the class MoniaDialog extends ComponentDialog as done in the Microsoft sample) :

```
const { ConfirmPrompt, OAuthPrompt, ComponentDialog, DialogSet, DialogTurnStatus, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { SignInDialog, SIGN_IN_DIALOG } = require('./signInDialog');
const { MoniaDialog } = require('./../moniaDialog');
const { polyfills } = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const { CardFactory } = require('botbuilder-core');

const SSO_DIALOG = 'SsoDialog';
const SSO_WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'SsoWaterfallDialog';
const OAUTH_PROMPT = 'OAuthPrompt';
const CONFIRM_PROMPT = 'ConfirmPrompt';

class SsoDialog extends MoniaDialog {
    constructor() {
        super(SSO_DIALOG, process.env.connectionName);

        this.addDialog(new SignInDialog())
        this.addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
            connectionName: process.env.connectionName,
            text: 'Please Sign In',
            title: 'Sign In',
            timeout: 300000
        }));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(SSO_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.promptStep.bind(this),
            this.oauth.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = SSO_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }

    async run(context, accessor) {
        const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.add(this);
        const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
        const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
        if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        }
    }

    async promptStep(step) {
        try {
            console.log("1")
            return await step.beginDialog(OAUTH_PROMPT);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return await step.endDialog();
        }
    }

    async oauth(step) {
        console.log("2")
        const id = step.context.activity.from.id
        const tokenResponse = step.result;
        console.log(tokenResponse)
        return step.beginDialog(SIGN_IN_DIALOG, tokenResponse)
    }
}

module.exports.SsoDialog = SsoDialog;
module.exports.SSO_DIALOG = SSO_DIALOG;
```

In the console I get the `"1"` message, but I don't get the `"2"`, because it crashes during the `OAUTH_PROMPT` dialog.

My manifest (summarised) is this :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.11/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "2.0.1",
    "manifestVersion": "1.11",
    "id": "392077da-6e68-43cd-897e-b45746da6a58",
    "packageName": "monia.app",
    "name": {
        "short": "Monia",
        "full": "Monia CRM"
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "outline.png",
        "color": "color.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "showLoadingIndicator": true,
     "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "7e48fa83-a08b-44b1-bf7d-59a3a042965c",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "token.botframework.com",
        "app.monia.ai"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "7e48fa83-a08b-44b1-bf7d-59a3a042965c",
        "resource": "api://botid-7e48fa83-a08b-44b1-bf7d-59a3a042965c"
    },
    "subscriptionOffer": {
        "offerId": "neodeal.monia"
    }
}
```

The id value is what I got from the Teams Developer Portal
The botId value is what I got from Azure App Registrations
webApplicationInfo is the same values as botId and in Azure App Registrations/Expose an API

.env.prod file:

```
MicrosoftAppType="Multi-tenant"
MicrosoftAppId="7e48fa83-a08b-44b1-bf7d-59a3a042965c"
MicrosoftAppPassword="bkc************"
MicrosoftAppTenantId="2152c805-66a7-4c7d-aad6-4ab6172cd85d"
AppCatalogTeamAppId="75c8f873-42f5-4f11-b5c2-60d05205eee8"
connectionName="Monia"
```

My version of botbuilder-dialogs:
`"botbuilder-dialogs": "~4.15.0"`

My index.js (summarised):

```
const {
    BotFrameworkAdapter,
    createBotFrameworkAuthenticationFromConfiguration,
    ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory,
    CloudAdapter,
    ConversationState,
    MemoryStorage,
    UserState
} = require('botbuilder');

const { DialogBot } = require('./bots/dialogBot');
const { MainDialog } = require('./dialogs/mainDialog');

const credentialsFactory = new ConfigurationServiceClientCredentialFactory({
    MicrosoftAppId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    MicrosoftAppPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    MicrosoftAppType: process.env.MicrosoftAppType,
    MicrosoftAppTenantId: process.env.MicrosoftAppTenantId
});

const botFrameworkAuthentication = createBotFrameworkAuthenticationFromConfiguration(null, credentialsFactory);

const adapter = new CloudAdapter(botFrameworkAuthentication);

app.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
    await adapter.process(req, res, (context) => bot.run(context));
})
```

Do you have any idea of what might be causing this? Everything seems right in the Azure Portal, and the same code works fine for my local side-loaded app.

I couldn't find anything useful related to this error.

Please note that we are at the same time pushing an offer as you can see in the manifest (`subscriptionOffer`) and it might be related but it also might be not, I don't know.

Comment: Hello Team,

Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately it does not help, even when changing for those two values in the env file (already tried this and retried). The configuration is already inspired from this sample.

The problem is not in the code, since it works perfectly well with another app/manifest.

I tried to follow the exact configuration but it still doesn’t work for the Monia app.

Looking forward your guidance,

Comment: @nfroidef-We have tested the sample with our side with OATH_PROMPT it is working fine but for sign in dialogs, we are not able to test the code. Could you please provide the code for the sign_In_dialoge implementation so that we can try it from our end also share code repo, if possible.

Comment: Hello Sayali, stackoverflow flags the comment as too long for my 70 lines file. I have invited you to my repo, you can find the file under the path ./dialogs/ssoDialogs/signInDialog.js

Comment: Could you please confirm once, is this happening for specific OS (desktop, web or mobile)?

Comment: I can confirm you that this problem happens on all the OS (desktop, web and mobile)